# Getting users who like a web page with Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm struggling with the Facebook API. What I want to do is to be able to look at a user's feed, see which web pages they clicked "Like" on, and then get the other users who like the same web page. I'm having two problems.

1) Whenever I get the feed of a user, all of the "Likes" are removed from the feed. Its very frustrating because its like Facebook will give me everything except for exactly what I'm looking for!

2) I can't seem to get a list of user IDs who like a certain URL. I've tried using FQL like this:

SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=114324145263104

As was suggested in another SO question, but that returned nothing on all of my attempts.

Does anyone know how to do this, or if its even possible? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to like? You said a web page, but the id you provided is just for an external web link... It is possible depending on what type of object in the graph you are trying to query...

Comment: So for example, lets say I go to the oatmeal and decide to like his comic about angry birds. That then posts on my wall that says "Spencer Likes such and such oatmeal comic" and it has a link to http://theoatmeal.com/whatever-comic. What I want to do is see which web links someone has "Liked" and then compare that to their friends. Does that make sense? Let me know if now I'll clarify more.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different query for getting the linkes of a url

```
SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me()
```

In your case it is.

```
SELECT user_id FROM url_like WHERE url = "http://www.domain.com/"
```

Comment: The second one will not work as the field url is not indexed. As stated by facebook docs

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.  This is what i do

https://graph.facebook.com/URL

OR if you have multiple URLs click to

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=URL1,URL2,URL3